# Doctrine 2 how to prevent dropping foreign keys

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently using Symfony2 with Doctrine. I added some foreign keys directly to my database without using relationships in Doctrine. It seems everytime I performed a `doctrine:schema:update --force`, all my foreign keys will be dropped. This is verified by running `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`.

Is there a way I can prevent doctrine from dropping manually-created foreign keys? Or is there a way I can create foreign keys using annotations without relationships?

Comment: I don't think so. You should decide between either using doctrine and having your database schema 100% defined by it or not using the update at all (changing the database manually).

Answer (score 2):

Like [**sgoettschkes**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372562/sgoettschkes), I do not think it is possible to do exactly what you are asking for (but you could write a ticket about it for future versions! I did not even find one and it seems like a good idea..!):

> I don't think so. You should decide between either using doctrine and having your database schema 100% defined by it or not using the update at all (changing the database manually).

- [**sgoettschkes**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372562/sgoettschkes)

However, until then, what I would suggest you is to write a script with native SQL and run it in (after) your doctrine schema:update stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use doctrine:schema:update in production, take a look at Doctrine Migrations to run in production so you know exactly which queries you're running after you deploy.

You could add indexes manually or renaming them manually. The update schema feature is meant to be used during development where you can change between different versions of your schema frequently and the content of your database is much less valuable. If you want to test the indexes in development you can recreate them manually for such ocassion, but I believe those cases will not happen very often.

I do not know why would you like not to define a relationship anyway, since all that it does is create this index, plus other functionalities which can be disabled by queries.